# Unauthorized Response headers error in webjobs

Tags: azure, header, authorization, azure-webjobs

I have 3 out of 4 jobs in a job collection in Azure App Service. Post every deployment i have to update 3 webjobs with authentication headers so the scheduler can trigger these jobs.

Here is the error when i try to run any of those webjobs from the portal.

[image]

Once i add authentication headers (i copy them from the one that have them), i am able to run all other 3 webjobs.

[image]

Is there anyway to avoid updating these headers after every deployment for my azure app service (webapp) that contains all these webjobs.

Thanks a lot.